# How do I use Nant/Ant naming patterns?

Tags: ant, nant

I have to admit that I always forgot the syntactical intracacies of the naming patterns for Nant (eg. those used in filesets). The double asterisk/single asterisk stuff seems to be very forgettable in my mind.

Can someone provide a definitive guide to the naming patterns?

Comment: I have read the reference. And re-read it. And re-read it. I just think it has a really poor set of examples and is unclear in its message.

Comment: Maybe you can specify exactly what you're trying to achive and someone can provide a better answer?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

The rules are:

- a single star (*) matches zero or more characters *within a path name*
- a double star (**) matches zero or more characters *across directory levels*
- a question mark (?) matches exactly one character within a path name

Another way to think about it is double star (**) matches slash (/) but single star (*) does not.

Let's say you have the files:

1. bar.txt
2. src/bar.c
3. src/baz.c
4. src/test/bartest.c

Then the patterns:

- `*.c`             matches nothing (there are no .c files in the current directory)
- `src/*.c`     matches 2 and 3
- `*/*.c`         matches 2 and 3 (because * only matches one level)
- `**/*.c`       matches 2, 3, and 4 (because ** matches any number of levels)
- `bar.*`         matches 1
- `**/bar.*`   matches 1 and 2
- `**/bar*.*` matches 1, 2, and 4
- `src/ba?.c` matches 2 and 3

Comment: I think that this is a much better explanation than the Nant reference. Cheers!

Comment: What does src/*/** match? I would expect it to be 4, but my experience with maven seems to indicate that you match any files in any folders you need src/*/*/**

Comment: what would `**.c` match?

Comment: I don't use Ant any more, so I'm not in a place to answer follow-up questions. You should ask a new question or, even better, find the answer and then submit an edit to my answer.

Comment: What if there is a space in the path? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731763/how-to-exclude-files-with-spaces-in-the-path-in-sonar

Comment: Can someone explain the rationale behind why `**/bar.*` matches `bar.txt`, which does not contain a slash?

Comment: @sitaktif One way to think about it is that `bar.txt` is implicitly `./bar.txt` (`.` means the current directory). So that list is really `./bar.txt`, `./src/bar.c`, etc. and the `./` is assumed.

Comment: How'd I match zero or one character, for example both `test.yaml` and `test.yml`? `test.y*ml` works but is too wide.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I don't know! You should post a new question so that more people see it. This one is over nine years old!

Comment: The missing example:

`**`.   matches 1, 2, 3, and 4

Answer (score 24):

Here's a few extra pattern matches which are not so obvious from the documentation. Tested using NAnt for the example files in benzado's answer:

1. bar.txt
2. src/bar.c
3. src/baz.c
4. src/test/bartest.c

- `src**`                      matches 2, 3 and 4
- `**.c`                        matches 2, 3, and 4
- `**ar.*`                    matches 1 and 2
- `**/bartest.c/**`  matches 4
- `src/ba?.c/**`        matches 2 and 3

Comment: small note: with ant (1.8.2) \**.c is no replacement for \**/\*.c

Answer (score 6):

Double asterisks (`**`) are associated with the folder-names matching, whereas single symbols asterisk (`* = multi characters`) as well as the question-mark (`? = single character`) are used to match the file-names.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Nant reference](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/fileset.html). The fileset patterns are:

'*' matches zero or more characters, e.g. *.cs
'?' matches one character, e.g. ?.cs

And '**' matches a directory tree e.g. src/**/*.cs will find all cs files in any sub-directory of src.