# Confusion with ANT pattern syntax and possible variations

Tags: ant, design-patterns

I am working on an ANT pattern parser as part of a large server project.

There are some good examples of ANT patterns in the answer to this post: [How do I use Nant/Ant naming patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835/how-do-i-use-nant-ant-naming-patterns?answertab=votes#tab-top) however, I am still confused about some possible permutations.

One of the examples on the ANT pattern documentation here http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/types/fileset.html is as follows:

> `**/test/**`   Matches all files that have a test element in their path, including test as a filename.

My understanding is that `**` matches one or more directories and also files under those directories. So I would expect `**/test/**` to match `src/test/subfolder/file.txt` and `test/file2.txt` but this statement seems to imply that it would also match a file named `src/test`. Is this correct even though there is a `/` after the `test` in the pattern?

Also, its not clear whether the following patterns would be valid:

```
folder**
folder1/folder**
**folder/file.txt
```

I would imagine that they would work the same as

```
folder*/**
folder1/folder*/**
**/*folder/file.txt
```

but are they allowed?

Comment: Create some folders and empty files, write a test build file with `<pathconvert>` and `<fileset>`, and you will see how the patterns actually work.

Comment: Good point but I guess I was hoping to learn the pattern syntax without actually learning to use NAnt...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some testing with NAnt as per *coolcfan*'s suggestion and answered my own question. The patterns in the question are all valid.

Based on the following files from the link in my question above:

1. bar.txt
2. src/bar.c
3. src/baz.c
4. src/test/bartest.c

The following unexpected patterns are also valid:

- `src**`                      matches 2, 3 and 4
- `**.c`                        matches 2, 3, and 4
- `**ar.*`                    matches 1 and 2
- `**/bartest.c/**`  matches 4
- `src/ba?.c/**`        matches 2 and 3

For completeness, these are in addition to the following patterns taken from the link in my question above:

- `*.c`             matches nothing (there are no .c files in the current directory)
- `src/*.c`     matches 2 and 3
- `*/*.c`         matches 2 and 3 (because * only matches one level)
- `**/*.c`       matches 2, 3, and 4 (because ** matches any number of levels)
- `bar.*`         matches 1
- `**/bar.*`   matches 1 and 2
- `**/bar*.*` matches 1, 2, and 4
- `src/ba?.c` matches 2 and 3