# How do I match URL using MockMvc's redirectedUrlPattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I've been trying to verify the redirect URL of the controller I'm testing but no matter what pattern I use, the test always fails. Even calling `andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern("*"))` fails. According to the docs, it's using Ant pattern, so I'm not sure why it keeps failing. I'm sure that the redirect URL is being set because `redirectUrl` works properly.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to match everything. It definitively distinguishes between absolute and relative paths.

/**/* matches all absolute paths

**/* matches all relative paths

Examples of what is possible:

- [Learning Ant path style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/learning-ant-path-style)
- [How do I use Nant/Ant naming patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835/how-do-i-use-nant-ant-naming-patterns)
- [Confusion with ANT pattern syntax and possible variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211196/confusion-with-ant-pattern-syntax-and-possible-variations)

If you give a concrete example of something you want to match I can give you a pattern that will work

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old topic but I was able to do this validation like the example below:

```
        this.mockMvc
            .perform(get("/oauth2/authorization/a-registration-id")
                    .param("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:3000/api/callback")
                    .with(csrf())
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isFound())
            .andExpect(header().string("Location", containsString("redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/callback")));
```