# Adding local .aar files to my gradle build

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, aar

So I have created an Android library and successfully compiled it into a .aar file. I called this aar file: `"projectx-sdk-1.0.0.aar"`. Now I want my new project to depend on this aar so what I have done is follow [this post](http://life.nimbco.us/referencing-local-aar-files-with-android-studios-new-gradle-based-build-system/).

But the post confuses me since I do not get the desired result:

> The package name of the aar is : `com.projectx.photosdk` and the module inside is called `sdk`

Here is my current project structure:

```
|-SuperAwesomeApp
|--.idea
|--gradle
|--App
|---aars
|----projectx-sdk-1.0.0.aar
|---build
|---jars
|---src
|---build.gradle
```

And here is my Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aars'
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'


    compile 'com.projectx.photosdk:sdk:1.0.0@aar'
//    compile files( 'aars/sdk-1.0.0.aar' ) // Does not work either
}
```

**EDIT**

The errors I am getting:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'SuperAwesomeApp'
     Could not find com.projectx.photosdk:sdk:1.0.0.
     Required by:
     SuperAwesomeApp:App:unspecified
```

Comment: I too had a same problem to solve that i'm going on with ur solution actually i'm new to android studio i'ad a doubt what do you say about module inside is called sdk means i can't get u then how can i use this line  compile 'com.projectx.photosdk:sdk:1.0.0@aar' can u plz help me to solve.

Comment: You can refer this working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029048/4136992

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You put your `flatDir` block in the wrong `repostories` block. The `repositories` block inside `buildscript` tells Gradle where to find the Android-Gradle plugin, but not the rest of the dependencies. You need to have another top-level `repositories` block like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}
```

I tested this and it works okay on my setup.

Comment: I'm impressed this worked! Any official documentation about that?

Comment: its not working for me , i have added flatDir{dirs 'aars'} still i am getting the error on compile line of aar.... :(

Answer (score 43):

With recent versions of Android Studio, tested with 1.3, to use local .AAR file and not one fetched from maven/jcenter repository, just go to **File > New > New module** and choose **Import .JAR/.AAR Package**.

What you will end up with is a new module in your project that contains very simple **build.gradle** file that looks more or less like this:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('this-is-yours-package-in-aar-format.aar'))
```

Of course, other projects have to reference this new module with regular  **compile project** directive.  So in a project that uses this new module which is simple a local .aar file has this in it's **build.gradle**

```
[...]
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    [...]

    compile project(':name-of-module-created-via-new-module-option-described-above')
}
[...]
```

Comment: Nice! If you are intimidated by editing the gradle (or can be bothered writing the module name out), double click on the new module you just added and it will open up the project structure window. From there, you can select your app module and click the + icon at the bottom and select whatever modules you please.

Comment: have imported the module, and in my project it got created as well with only an .aar file of the same module and a simple gradle file as described in the answer. Has it been imported correctly? If yes, then how to start using the classes within it?

Comment: This is right. Here is the [doc](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Handling-transitive-dependencies-for-local-artifacts-jars-and-aar-).

Comment: There is no " Import .JAR/.AAR Package" option.

Comment: this used to work up until last year, not sure when it happened, but it's broken now. The jar classes are recognized by the app but not by the IDE.

Answer (score 24):

In Android Studio 3.1.3 with gradle 3.0.1.
Simply adding `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])` or `implementation files('libs/app-release.aar')` without any other `flatdir` works.

Answer (score 5):

These days (over 1 year after this question) with Android Studio >1.0, local dependency does work properly:

- The android sdk looks for dependencies in a default local repo of: `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/`
- In a local library project you can publish the aar to this directory.  Here's a snippet that can be added to your module's `build.gradle` file (ex: sdk/build.gradle)

  ```
  apply plugin: 'maven'

  uploadArchives {
      repositories {
          mavenDeployer {
              repository(url: "file://localhost" + System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
                  + "/extras/android/m2repository/")
              pom.version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
              pom.groupId = 'your.package'
              pom.artifactId = 'sdk-name'
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  - some reference gradle docs http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html
- In your library project, run `./gradlew uploadArchives` to publish the aar to that directory
- In the application project you want to use the library in, add the dependency to your project/app/build.gradle. `compile 'your.package:sdk-name:1.0-SNAPSHOT'`

For local dependency, the next gradle build should find the previously deployed archive and *that's it!*

---

In my case, I use the above for local dev, but also have a Bamboo continuous integration server for the Library that publishes each build to a shared Nexus artifact repository. The full library code to deploy the artifact then becomes:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            if (System.getenv("BAMBOO_BUILDNUMBER") != null) {
                // Deploy to shared repository
                repository(url: "http://internal-nexus.url/path/") {
                    authentication(userName: "user", password: "****")
                }
                pom.version = System.getenv("BAMBOO_BUILDNUMBER")
            } else {
                // Deploy to local Android sdk m2repository
                repository(url: "file://localhost" + System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
                        + "/extras/android/m2repository/")
                pom.version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            }

            pom.groupId = 'your.package'
            pom.artifactId = 'sdk-name'
        }
    }
}
```

In order to tell applications to download from my internal Nexus repository, I added the internal Nexus maven repository just above jcenter() in both "repositories" blocks in the project/build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://internal-nexus.url/path/"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

And application dependency then looks like `compile 'your.package:sdk-name:45'` When I update the 45 version to 46 is when my project will grab the new artifact from the Nexus server.

Comment: I just tried Stan Kurdziel's suggestion and was able to resolve my question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445399/create-an-aar-with-multiple-aars-jars>

Answer (score 2):

With the newest Gradle version there is now a slightly updated way of doing what Stan suggested (see [maving publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html))

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.your-group-id'
            artifactId 'your-artifact-id'
            version 'x.x.x'

            // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url("file:" + System.getenv("HOME") + "/.m2/repository")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems adding .aar files as local dependency is not yet supported(Planned to be supported in 0.5.0 Beta)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863

But the way you are using your library in dependency will only work if your library is on central maven repository or in the local maven repository.

Refer this for How to use local maven repository to use .aar in module dependencies.

http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds

Comment: The entire point of the blog post he linked to is how to get around the fact that the Android-Gradle plugin doesn't support local AARs by creating a fake repository that it can look in when using Maven coordinate-style dependency includes.

Answer (score 0):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts) assuming you put the files in `my-libs` subdirectory relative to where the build file is located:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(
        fileTree("my-libs/") {
            // You can add as many include or exclude calls as you want
            include("my-first-library.aar")
            include("another-library.aar")
            // You can also include all files by using a pattern wildcard
            include("*.jar")
            exclude("the-bad-library.jar")
        }
    )
    // Other dependencies...
}
```

For more ways to do this, see [Gradle documentations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:file_dependencies) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850031/8583692) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70849466/8583692).