# Can an Android library JAR depend on an Android library AAR?

Tags: android, jar, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have an Android library project `FooLib`. `FooLib` references things like Android `Context`s but doesn't require any resource files (things in `res/`) so I am currently packaging this as a JAR for my app to consume.

I now want to make `FooLib` depend on `BarLib`, but `BarLib` *does* use resources so I can't package `BarLib` as a JAR. Instead, it is packaged as an AAR. Is it possible for me to have `FooLib` depend on `BarLib` but continue to package `FooLib` as a JAR? Or, does having an AAR dependency in `FooLib` force me to make it an AAR also?

Comment: How can a JAR "depend" on anything? It's just a container for classes.

Comment: Hmm yeah maybe I should have phrased it -- "Can an Android Library project that can be packaged as a JAR depend on another Android Library project that uses resources (and is therefore packaged as an AAR) and still be packaged as a JAR?" I suspect the answer is no, but I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a project that includes JAR files and AAR files as dependencies (see note below), then you can have Android-specific JARs as dependencies that rely on classes in the Android APIs, though the JAR files can't contain Android resources as you already know. Just because it depends on Android classes doesn't mean it needs to be packaged as an AAR.

Here I'm talking about what's perhaps a single-module project that includes a number of JAR and AAR dependencies. A JAR file is just a collection of class files (and perhaps non-Android resources and other files) and doesn't have a sense of dependencies, so there's nothing to break. When it comes time to do the build, the builder just bundles everything together and packages it and doesn't check to see if the JAR has unresolvable dependencies on other classes -- you'll find out with classloader exceptions at runtime.

If you're talking about library *modules* in a multimodule project in the IDE, then that's a different matter. If you have a module A which can compile to a plain JAR (it uses the `apply plugin: 'java'` statement in the build file), then it can't depend on an Android module (`apply plugin: 'android-library'`) which compiles to an AAR. This will likely never be fixed, or at least not in the foreseeable future: it's because Android modules have a much more complex notion of source folders, and the Java plugin in Gradle can't understand Android's source sets.

The converse is true, though -- Android modules *can* depend on plain Java modules.

**NOTE**

Due to limitations not yet resolved in the Gradle builder, you can't access local AARs in the same way you do as JARs in your build files (by referencing them via `compile files(...)` statements); you have to fool Gradle into thinking they're in some sort of Maven repository (perhaps by putting them in an *actual* Maven repository, which can be local). See [Adding local .aar files to my gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882804/adding-local-aar-files-to-my-gradle-build/21890937#21890937) for a workaround if you need it.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about library modules in a multimodule project. Let's assume module A and module B are both Android modules (both have the `apply plugin: 'android-library'` statements in their build.gradle files). It seems that I can still use http://stackoverflow.com/a/19484146/128948 to package module A as a JAR if it requires no resources. If module B does need resources and I have it packaged as an AAR, can I have module A depend on module B and still package module A as a JAR?

Comment: That looks like it should work. android-library plugins can depend on each other, and Jake Wharton's script looks like it should work to have it snag a JAR output out of the module. I believe with these changes in place the module will generate two outputs, both AAR and JAR.

Comment: A question on this...because for instance appcompat-v7 provides both .aar and .jar in the same maven subfolder...when i specify the dependency though, gradle always picks the .aar file and of course the gradle java plugin doesn't know what it is...is there a way to pick the .jar over the .aar even if the POM specifies package .aar?

Comment: Appcompat only supplies .aar. I don't know where you're seeing a .jar version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Because [AAR format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) does not contain classes directly as jar files do it is no use for a non Android project. Therefore it would be better to make FooLib an AAR.

Another solution would be to extract jar library from BarLib and depend on it.

Comment: I'm not looking to use FooLib in a non-Android project, but I'd like to keep FooLib as a JAR to maximize compatibility since if it was an AAR, I wouldn't be able to use it in my Ant-based Android apps. To answer the original question, are you saying "no, an Android library JAR cannot depend on an Android library AAR"?