# Unable to reference classes from aar in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, aar

Total Android Studio newby here.

Using Android Studio `0.5.9`, I successfully created an `.arr`, now I'm trying to include it in an android app's build.

The sync completes successfully using `compile files('libs/scanner-0.1.aar')` as can be seen from the image below (or at least I think it completes successfully)

[image]

However, when I try to reference any class from the `scanner-0.1.aar` I get a `cannot resolve symbol error` as if the classes where not found/loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the lib project on the same machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding local .aar files to my gradle build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882804/adding-local-aar-files-to-my-gradle-build)

Comment: @EugenMartynov what do you mean? Everything is local in my machine

Comment: sry had not seen it. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its too late but this is how it works for me:

-*scanner-0.1-aar* must be inside *app/libs* inside your project.

-Your gradle must contain these lines:

```
repositories{
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

   dependencies{
       compile ':scanner-0.1.aar@aar'
   }
```