# Import library module that has dependency on local aar file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

I have an Android Instant App with following structure:

- B: base module
- Installed: installed app module
- Instant: instant app module
- F: feature with functional specific to Installed app. F depends on local aar library `local-lib` located in `project\F\libs`.

`F`'s build.gradle is following:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    api ":local-lib@aar"
}
```

I tried to include `F` module to `Installed` app module like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':B')
    implementation project(':F')
}
```

But gradle couldn't resolve `local-lib`, giving error:

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Installed:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find :local-lib:.
  Searched in the following locations:

      ... some remote repositories ...

  Required by:
      project :Installed > project :F
```

I tried to duplicate `libs` folder to `project\Installed\libs`, and it worked. So basically I need 2 copies of `local-lib` to make this work? How should I organise imports to avoid duplication? Perfect case would be if `libs` folder was inside `F` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the cleanest way to make it work would be to use some local repository, like a Maven, publish your `local-lib` here, and reference it from here, and do the same for each of your libraries. When you publish to an artifact repository manager - let's say a Maven - you will have your *.aar* coupled with a *pom* file, containing all the needed dependencies.

You have to keep in mind here that your aar is kind of a flat file, meaning, while you reference it somewhere, there is not way to keep track of the transitive dependencies of it (that's the job of the *pom* files on Maven).

This means that when you reference `F` in `Installed`, the `F` *aar* is added, but `Installed` doesn't know that it has to get `local-lib` in order for `F` to work properly, or doesn't know where. That's why you have lines on the remote repositories: gradle searches everywhere (in every possible place = in every repository you have listed) for the dependency.

When you copy/paste the code as a module of your project, the gradle knows what are the transitive dependencies because it can access the gradle file for each dependency.

When you copy the aar directly inthe Installed/libs folder, it also works because gradle checks here (you probably have a compile line in your gradle checking for that folder).

If you want to keep the flat file, you should try putting somewhere reachable by all modules, on the same folder level (take a look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172413/cant-use-local-aar-file-inside-the-library-module?rq=1) question), or you could try to add the local-lib as an Android module project, and not just put it in the libs folder.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer ;)
If you choose to go for maven, take a look at: https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/ and be careful about the pom generation (dependencies are not generated by default)