# How to add AAR library in project with New Build System?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

How to add AAR library in Android Studio 1.0.2? I search about this and I found a posts, where saying that I need to put library file into libs folder. But it doesn't work. This library is for internal use and never published in open access. File build.gradle contains this line:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'])
```

But Studio can't find resources from library. I've try to add it manually:

```
compile(name:'somelib-1.32', ext:'aar')
```

And when I get this error:

```
"Error:Failed to find: :somelib-1.32:"
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Where does the library reside? Is it in a Maven-style artifact repository?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28816265/2745762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build System didn't manage very well the `-`, as for res files.

Replace it by `_` or CamelCase, so `somelib-1.32.aar` become `somelib_1.32.aar`

**EDIT :** Also don't forget to add `flatDirs[...]` to your project `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I remove `-1.32` from library file name, but nothing changed.

Comment: @BArtWell se my Edited answer

Comment: Actually replacing `-` with `_` made a difference?  I am surprised this matters for jar and aar names...

Comment: I get below error.
Error:Project AreaDUMApp: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: /Users/mango/Android/bsm_areadum/areadum/AreaDUMApp/libs/versioncontrol_android_1.4.4 2.aar