# How to import a .aar file into Android Studio 1.1.0 and use it in my code

Tags: android

I have read a lot answers related to this topic, but none of them have worked to solve my problem, so need help with this:

I need to import a .aar file into a project created with **Android Studio 1.1.0**, I have imported it using the "New Module" option and actually I don't receive any error, I can build the application and run it, but when I try to use a class from this .aar file Android Studio doesn´t find the reference to it, let's say it can´t recognize the package that I want to include in my code.

You are maybe thinking that I must add the dependency, I have already done that, It seems to not work.

So someone could tell me which is the correct way to import and use a .aar file in **Android Studio 1.1.0**

Comment: .aar's are not so easy to import locally, they are intented to be provided through a maven/ivy server. They are not like .jar libs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding local .aar files to Gradle build using "flatDirs" is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working)

Comment: It is similar, but any of thoses answers worked for me, so I need a very well explain process of how to import a .aar file and use it in my code, but using Android Studio 1.1.0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After reading a lot of answers on Stackoverflow, I found the solution for my problem, I want you to know which were the steps I followed in order to reproduce it:

1. Add a .aar file in my libs folder.
2. Use "New Module" option under File menu.
3. Import the .aar file.
4. Build gradle and compile the project.

When I tried to use the new module in my app, It didn't recognize any class inside the new module.

The problem is related to the version of Gradle, I was using **1.1.0** and there is a bug in this version, so my suggestion is to change the version to **1.0.1**, there is an Issue already open in order to fix this problem https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162634

You should change the version in the build.gradle file located in the root of your project.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {

    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

You can find additional information about this problem here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/1Ho_c8dALQQ

I guess in version 1.2.0 this problem will be solved.

Comment: You made my day as well. :) And the problem still seems to exist in version 1.3.0. :(

Comment: Upgrade gradle version 1.3.1

Answer (score 95):

To import an .aar library:

1. Go to File>New>New Module
2. Select "Import .JAR/.AAR Package" and click next.
3. Enter the path to the .aar file and click finish.
4. Go to File>Project Structure (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
5. Under "Modules," in left menu, select "app."
6. Go to "Dependencies" tab.
7. Click the green "+" in the upper right corner.
8. Select "Module Dependency"
9. Select the new module from the list.

Comment: "Enter the path to .aar file and click finish." when I click finish, the window trembles and nothing happens, im guessing the trembling means an error, any ideas?

Comment: I was trying to do step 3 (enter the path to .aar file and click finish) but I could only enter the path to .aar file. The finish button was faded (could click on it)...

Comment: @pb772, did you type in the file path of the .aar file? If so, try locating it in the file browser, you might have made a typo in the path. It would also be worth testing a different .aar file to see if the problem is with the file you are trying to use.

Comment: Thank you.. Worked like  a charm

Answer (score 1):

I follow steps in both answers but finally I need to add this line to my `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir { dirs 'aars'} // this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
```