# building an aar module

Tags: android, aar

First time i build an aar module. I am able to convert my app into an aar module. And i create another new app, and add this aar file into the project. However, I encountered this error.

```
Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'civ_border_color' in package 'com.example.com'
```

I have searched for the answer, and recommendation like
replacing
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
with 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto" or
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.example.com"

I have tried. And i notice the files that have error, are auto generate files, i am not suppose to change them. Is there any steps that i have missed out creating the aar file. BTW, the compilation of the aar file is successful.  Any useful information that i missed out , please do point out. Not vote down. Coz i really have no idea what I have missed out.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you refer to the aar in your new app？

Comment: By following this [Link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826717/how-to-import-a-aar-file-into-android-studio-1-1-0-and-use-it-in-my-code

Comment: Check the issues I add below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add

```
repositories {
  flatDir {
     dirs 'libs'
  }
}
```

in your project's build.gradle?

Did you add

```
compile(name: 'xxx', ext: 'aar')。
```

in your module's build.gradle?

Comment: i didn't add anything manually, only use this [Link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826717/how-to-import-a-aar-file-into-android-studio-1-1-0-and-use-it-in-my-code

Comment: I check the gradle files, it does not have what you stated above.

Comment: Then you should add both of the code above into your build.gradle.

Comment: still not working.  I check. build gradle has compile project(':sdk-debug')   and i have added  flatDir {
     dirs 'libs'
  }

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. To give a hand for anyone that facing this issue. When building your aar module. Make sure the layout is change from

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto"
```

Compile the module, and then add this module to a new project. (The issue solved, I am now encounter different error now, gonna post another question.) Thanks.

Comment: What is lib-auto?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky what is res-auto anyway ?