# How to install Realm in android studio offline?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, realm

I want to install Realm in android studio without internet access . I want to download a file like a jar file and add it to my project . Is it possible , how ?

Comment: Why aren't you using Gradle, do a gradle sync, then turn on gradle offline mode???

Comment: My android studio doesn't access internet . I should download possibly a file  in another computer and move to that computer .

Comment: You are posting on the internet right now

Comment: My android studio is installed in another computer that doesn't access internet .

Answer (score 0):

You may download it from here https://bintray.com/realm/maven/realm-android-library/3.4.0#files/io%2Frealm%2Frealm-android-library%2F3.4.0

[image]

Comment: Is this a jar file ?

Comment: No, it's a .aar file. Here you may check how to add .aar file in Android Studio - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826717/how-to-import-a-aar-file-into-android-studio-1-1-0-and-use-it-in-my-code