# Hiding android.R resources in Android Studio 1.3+ autocomplete

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

Is it possible to configure Android Studio to display only the `@drawable` resources that are inside the **project** folder?

The project I'm working on is an Industry project and rarely requires me to use `R` resources.

[image]

Comment: you can make like this `@package:drawable/filename`

Comment: @FouadWahabi , AS doesn't recognize this command for *autocomplete*.

Comment: it's mentioned in the devoleper.android site : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html , I don't kno exactly how it works

Comment: @FouadWahabi I believe your suggestion requires the OP to type `@package:drawable/filename` for **each** autocomplete. I don't think this answers the OP's question about removing the unused resource references from the autocomplete list.

Comment: Found no solution yet. Typing the package name seems not like a good option to me.

Comment: It seems AS 1.3 can it. But haven't find out how. See here: https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/629490397677400064 and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Rox-HXhRfI&feature=youtu.be&t=144

Comment: Yes it looks like it does! I have edited the question title now because of it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do that actually, only library developers can choose to hide the resources in their `aar` distributions.

So you are dependent on library developers to do that for you. Luckily the latest Android support library should already have done this for you.

The way library developers can hide resources in their library is:

1. Create a new folder on the same level as `res` called `res-public` (name not important) with a subfolder called `values`:

> ```
> src
>     main
>          java
>          res
>          res-public
>              values
> ```

2. In that folder create a new file called `public.xml`, where you define all resources that you want to have public with their `name` followed by `type`

```xml
<resources>
    <public type="drawable" name="btn_login"/>
</resources>
```

3. Then make sure to reference this new folder in your `build.gradle` file:

```groovy
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs 'res', 'res-public'
    }

    defaultConfig {
       ...
    }
}
```

4. Make sure you are using at least version 1.3 of the Gradle plugin

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

5. Compile your library into an `aar` file and include that into your project. Only the `btn_login` resource will now be visible.

   - Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working/28816265#28816265) how to include a local `aar` file, so you can test without pushing to a Maven repo.

Comment: above solution didn't work for me. still, I am able to access the private resource in main app module

Comment: Indeed, this just excludes the resources from autocomplete. However, Android Studio should give you a warning if you try and use "hidden" resources. Note that namespaces are coming to resources pretty soon, which should enable true private resources: https://youtu.be/GlwvVJNWlWg?t=1448

Comment: but I am to get private resources in autocomplete. check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430517/unable-to-make-android-library-resources-private

Comment: How you manage to get it worked? Its not working for me (Gradle plugin: 3.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the AS's 'Code Completion' section, I didn't find any setting which allows to hide the SDK resources and use the app/lib resources instead:

[image]

The recently implemented feature, mentioned by StefMa, probably will not help you as it works the other way: it allows library developers to hide some of the resources from the aar package and show only selected portion of resources, aka *public recources*. Chris Banes made a good intro in this feature [here](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/8Rip6rQGK32).