# How to hide the android library resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a library but the **resources(drawables, layouts etc.)** that I have used in the library are accessible to the users who are implementing it.
I want to make my **resource folder hidden**.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863628/how-to-make-android-library-resources-private

Comment: Yes, it didn't work.

Comment: Try to explain what you did what didn't work, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: The accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863628/how-to-make-android-library-resources-private didn't work. I was still able to see my resources.