# Unable to make Android library resources private?

Tags: android, android-library

created **public.xml** in values and added public resource there

```
<resources>
<public type="drawable" name="image_public"/>
<public type="string" name="external_module_string_res_public"/>
<public type="layout" name="activity_main_public"/>
</resources>
```

but still, I am able to access to all resource from library module in the Main project.

tried this [Chris Banes's instruction](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/8Rip6rQGK32)
and this as well [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529877/hiding-android-r-resources-in-android-studio-1-3-autocomplete/31960895#31960895)

using 
**Android Studio 3.1.4**
and 
**`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`**

Comment: "created __public.xml__ in values" – Is that `res-public/values/`?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes i did that too

Comment: Found any solution? I also failed to make library resources private(Gradle plugin: 3.3.1)

Comment: @AlphonsaAugustine  NO