# Android .aar dependencies aren’t resolving in app project that depends on .aar

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, aar

i have created an android library AAR in android studio 2.1.3 in which i use the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0+'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.3'
```

now i am using this aar in an application but those dependencies were failing unless i add them to the dependencies of the new app.

i search here and i found that i need to add the following line:

```
compile (project(':LIBNAME-release')) {transitive = true}
```

but this didn't work. is there something i missed? or is it related to the obfuscation i did to the aar file? or is it a must to add these dependencies to the app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually include external aar package using Gradle for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-gradle-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile you project first:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Name-Of-Your-Project')
}
```

This is *Ashton Engberg's* suggestion from [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894387/3926506)

Comment: this is what i am using now. but the project asks for the dependencies i used inside the aar. shall i use the dependencies also in the app other than the aar