# Android NoClassDefFoundError for library's class inside a dependency

Tags: android, gradle

I created an Android library named "core" that use the Logger library (https://github.com/orhanobut/logger).

Here its `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Then I build a `.aar` of core library.

I add this library as a dependency into my application, by putting the `.aar`core files in the `libs` folder.

That's the `build.gradle` of my application :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.mypackage:core:1.0@aar'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

As you can see I have `multidex` activated.

It compile just fine but at runtime, at the first call to `Logger` I get an exception:

`stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/orhanobut/logger/Logger;`

Even if I set `transitive = true`

```
compile (com.mypackage:core:1.0@aar) {
        transitive=true
}
```

it doesn't work.

Thank you !

Comment: 1) Multidex is unrelated to the problem 2) When you have `compile 'com.mypackage:core:1.0@aar'`, it tries to find that from JCenter, not your local project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding local .aar files to Gradle build using "flatDirs" is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a couple of things in concert to get it to work.

1) In your library project

Add the following to your **project-level** gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    }
}
```

Be sure to use the right version of the plugin for your gradle version, check [here](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin#note-on-releases).

Add the following to your **module-level** gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group='com.github.YourPackage'// Doesn't have to be github, just an example
```

Also in this file, make sure your dependencies (the ones you want to be transitive) use `api` instead of `implementation` if you are using [Gradle 3.4+](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#new_configurations). If you are using a version of Gradle <3.4, `compile` is the way to go. Example:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
}
```

---

2) In your app project (which uses the library)

Add the following to your **module-level** gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.github.YourPackage:yourRepo:version@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Add the following to you **project-level** gradle file (but this will depend on where your library is served from, for me it's jitpack):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
            credentials { username 'yourAuthKey' }// Only for private repositories
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You shouldn't add the auth key as a string in build.gradle, put it in a property in your gradle.properties file.

Note 2: JitPack allows you to use for example `development-SNAPSHOT` as a version number for a gradle dependency. Android Studio caches these dependencies and **will not** re-download it when you push to your development branch. To overcome this, use commit hashes as version numbers during development or clear (delete) the cache files, located on Windows at `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-x.xx/descriptors/com.github.YourPackage/yourRepo`. (Needles to say, I learned this the hard way).

Comment: do you know how to modify this approach when app project imports the library as a local AAR file (i.e. not taken from some repository)?