# Android third party dependencies in internal use library (Artifactory)

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, artifactory

I'm developing a library for Android for internal use in our company, this library has third part dependencies and is stored in our own Artifactory repository.

The problem is that since we upgraded to Gradle 3 we don't have visibility of the dependencies of the library in the different projects in which we use the library.

Am I missing something, that's my build.gradle file of the library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

//Skitude Plugins
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
mavenCentral()
}

//Artifactory ID
def libraryGroupId = 'com.company.companylibrary'
def libraryArtifactId = 'library'
def libraryVersion = '0.0.6'   

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.6"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary= true
    }

    buildTypes {
        defaultConfig {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Dependencies ANDROID
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

    api 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    ...


}

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'library-core-release-local'

            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password

    }
    defaults {
        publications('aar')
        publishArtifacts = true

        properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'q.os': 'android', 'dev.team': 'core']
        publishPom = true
    }
}
}
```

For example when my library want to access volley library from my app without importing the dependecy again, so it's already imported in my library I get this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.skitude.Valdesqui, PID: 28489
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/DiskBasedCache;
                  at com.blabsolutions.skitudelibrary.Helpers.ProfileHelper.setupVolley(ProfileHelper.java:81)
                  at com.blabsolutions.skitudelibrary.SkitudeApplication.onCreate(SkitudeApplication.java:132)
                  at com.skitude.Valdesqui.CoorpApplication.onCreate(CoorpApplication.java:32)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                  at com.blabsolutions.skitudelibrary.Helpers.ProfileHelper.setupVolley(ProfileHelper.java:81) 
                  at com.blabsolutions.skitudelibrary.SkitudeApplication.onCreate(SkitudeApplication.java:132) 
                  at com.skitude.Valdesqui.CoorpApplication.onCreate(CoorpApplication.java:32) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 
                Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.skitude.Valdesqui-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk ()
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:373)
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:113)
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:78)
                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
                  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
                  at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
                  at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:535)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:568)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2046)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:787)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2261)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2201)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2192)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5776)
                        ... 8 more
```

Things that I tried:

- Upgarde from Gradle 3.1.0 to Gradle 4.4
- Disable default Proguard

Thanks

Comment: what is your logcat error?

Comment: There is no logcat error, everything goes right, but if I try to acces/import the third part dependencies from the library I can't do it,

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Did you ever manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to gradle 3+, you switch your compile's to implementation/api in your gradle as you know. However, you have left the line 'compile' for you pom.xml dependency creation. You should change the line;

```
pom.withXml {
    def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
            configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
            }
        }
```

with;

```
      pom.withXml {
                        def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                        configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                            def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at other similar SO threads, like:

- [Transitive Library dependencies are not found in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311507/transitive-library-dependencies-are-not-found-in-the-application)
- [Android NoClassDefFoundError for library's class inside a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765748/android-noclassdeffounderror-for-librarys-class-inside-a-dependency)

Especially the second seems to have a more thorough answer which involves modifying both the library project and the client project (the one using the library)