# Include an external aar library in android for android gradle tools 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

Need to include the external aar file in the project.

Earlier implementation of the task is:

```
compile(name:'libName-release', ext:'aar')
```

**I need to migrate to Android-Gradle-Plugin 3.x.x and wish to compile my aar libraries. What is the exact statement I should be writing?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working

Comment: @NahuelBarrios I'm migrating from gradle android plugin 2 to 3 and require solution for this.

Comment: What is the problem? It is not clear

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti please see updated question.