# ClassNotFoundException even though i have already added the libraries

Tags: android

Hi I have created one application in android studio adding picasso and volley library It works fine But when i convert the same application in library using     apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  and add that .aar file in another application  the volley gives  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest`  but when volley added again in the new application it works fine why is that? Why do I have to add volley again as I have already added it in the library?

Comment: share your build.gradle file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to declare the dependencies in the library as transitive. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35568233/1440565) for details.