# Add gradle dependencies(build.gradle) in .aar file Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I am having an android library project which is using third party libraries. I have created it's .aar file and imported the .aar file in a different project. Classes and resources are imported but the gradle libraries are not imported. I don't want to mention those dependencies again in the project.
Is there any way to import that project with .aar file or something else which include build.gradle or dependencies.

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326929/how-to-include-dependence-library-when-export-aar-file - when you export library then dependencies are not included by default

Comment: Adding `transitive=true` in dependencies doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAR file does not include external dependencies which are mention in `app/build.gradle` so instead of adding it directly we upload to local maven and integrate it.

To upload it in your local maven you can add the following function in `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://localhost" + System.getenv("HOME") + "/.m2/repository")
            pom.version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            pom.groupId = 'your.package'
            pom.artifactId = 'sdk-name'
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the pom version, groupId and artifactId according to how you want to use it.

If this process is completed you can integrate the library.

- In the `app/build.gradle` of the project in which you want to add the
  library specify the path.

  `implementation 'your.package:sdk-name:1.0-SNAPSHOT'`
- In the `project/build.gradle` add the following

  ```
  allprojects{
      ...
      mavenLocal()
  }
  ```

  This will search for the library in the local machine.

If still, you get some error try to invalidate caches and restart the android-studio from the File Menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are including this library in `dependencies` block then try to use `api` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: Currently I am using `implementation (name: 'my-library', ext: 'aar')` 
When I tried the same with `api` getting the same error of dependencies not foundr.
I have added .aar file in `libs` folder of my project and mentioned it's location in app-level gradle by 
`flatDir{  dirs 'libs'  }`

Could you please tell the proper format for `api` import statement.

Comment: I comment question directly, after spending some time for thinking I realized, that it's not a problem with including, rather it's a problem with exporting. So after update library try with both `implementation` and `api` which I think you used correctly and let me know if `api` was necessary

Comment: I have given a solution which is working for me, I need you to check it once.