# How to add .aar dependency in library module?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am having one `.aar` file of one library module.
I want to use it as a library or dependency in my other project's library module.
How do I do it?

I tried options provided at below links:
http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project/

It works only if I add `.aar` reference in my project's application module. But not working in library module.

Thanks.

Comment: please provide your `build.gradle`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding local .aar files to my gradle build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882804/adding-local-aar-files-to-my-gradle-build)

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile(name:'mylibmodule', ext:'aar')
}

Comment: @Swati check above link .

Answer (score 70):

Follow this setting and you will able to add `.aar` dependency to library module

**build.gradle (Project: ....)**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
            dirs project(':library_module').file('libs')
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':library_module')
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: library_module)**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile(name:'aar_file_name', ext:'aar')
}
```

**settings.gradle (Project Settings)**

```
include ':app', ':library_module'
```

Comment: dirs project(':library_module').file('libs') do the job

Comment: @Android, I am sorry since I answer it for a long time so I am not sure about the change. If you found the way for solving it, hope you can correct me. Thank you so much

Comment: No issue @PhanVanLinh

Comment: After lot of struggle, this answer help me to fix the issue.Thank you Phan Van Linh.

Answer (score 15):

In all modules (library or application) where you need the aar file you have to add in your `build.gradle` the repository:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

and add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
 }
```

You can use the top-level file to add the repositories, but you can't add the dependencies in the top-level file.
Pay attention to the relative path of the libs folder that you are using in the module.

Comment: I want library with resources.

Comment: What does it mean? The aar has the resources

Comment: @Swati You have to add the dependencies in your modules, not in your top-level file. Reading your comment you are adding the dependencies in the wrong file

Answer (score 8):

Sorry process involves 10 steps but these are super simple and easy.

**1-** New->Module

[image]

**2-** Select import .jar/aar package

[image]

**3-** Select your .aar file from location

[image]

**4-** We can see module is added but not configured with app module yet.

[image]

**5-** Go to Project Structure

[image]

**6-** Current project structure is like this one

[image]

**7-** Go to app module and press '+' icon

[image]

**8-** Select 3rd option Module dependency

[image]

**9-** Select newly added .arr module

[image]

**10-** you can see the new module attached with app module. Now click apply.

[image]

you can see we are good to go.
 [image]

Comment: I Miss this steps in Arctic Fox , If You find then please let me know :(

Comment: The dialog in step 2 is not available anymore in Chipmunk...

Answer (score 5):

I did it a bit differently than others have posted here...

My main goal was to create a library module that contained all the jar's and aar's that I would need. My main project would then depend on this library module - I only wanted a single line in the main project's build.gradle to link this dependency.

1. Add a new library module to the project: File -> New -> New Module -> Android Library
2. within the library module, open the build.gradle and add:

> ```
> // so that the library project can locate the aar in /libs
> repositories {
>     flatDir {
>         dirs 'libs'
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
> }
> ```

now you can pop all the jar's and aar's into the /libs folder of your library module.
Bonus: whatever the library name is doesn't matter, it's automatically discovered

Comment: I was trying the same thing but this didn't work for me. it looks at app/libs directory instead

Comment: I can't find the answer to this. There's hundreds of answers just like this one but none of them seem to work for me. Error is `Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting A
AR.`

Comment: @DanielWilson I'm facing the same issue, do you find any solution?

Comment: @WellingtonYogui see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074787/1866373

Answer (score 4):

1. File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR
2. import the .AAR file.
3. in library module build.gradle add the dependency
   dependencies{compile project(':Name-Of-Your-Module-aar')}

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Handling-transitive-dependencies-for-local-artifacts-jars-and-aar-

Comment: I was able to work through my problem following these steps. The settings.gradle and build.gradle files are automatically updated, leaving me to only implement step # 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to copy your aar file to the library module's libs folder. and in the app level build.gradle implement the dependency like below

```
implementation files('libs/aar_file_name.aar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Under dependencies in the module's build.gradle add the associated .aar files with

```
compileOnly files('libs/api-release.aar')
```

And then in the importing project's app/build.gradle add the .aar files with

```
implementation files('../../node_modules/react-native-misnap/android/libs/api-release.aar')
```