# How to add .aar file as a dependency in a Android library module

Tags: android

I have .aar(MyLib.aar) file and i want to create a new android library (MyNewLib.aar) which is dependent on MyLib.aar

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile(name:'mylib', ext:'aar')

}
```

When the build is completed the classes that are references to MyLib.aar, are not in the newly created MyNewLib.aar

i have checked this one

[How to add .aar dependency in library module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765190/how-to-add-aar-dependency-in-library-module)

it doesn't work

Comment: Go to build-> intermediates -> exploded-aars -> your_aar -> your_classes, Is all classes there? If Yes, then there is some issue of dependencies or your `aar` has some issues!\

Comment: @AndiGeeky the .aar file is there but no class of MyLib.aar

Comment: That means your `.aar` file is not properly generated. Generate `aar` again and try!

Answer (score 0):

put your aar file in libs folder then right click on that file and choose add as library and then sync now. it will be added to your project.