# implement a java local library to flutter plugin template

Tags: java, android, gradle, flutter, flutter-plugin

i'm trying to add a local library to a flutter plugin project.
the library is created directly in the root folder of the flutter project (not in the android folder)
So here is the structure:
MyFlutterProject:

```
_ lib
   __ flutterPlugin.dart
_ MyLibrary   
   __ build.gradle
   __ setting.gradle
   __ src
   __ ...
_ Android
   __ build.gradle
   __ ...
[...]
```

This is my [android] build.gradle file:

```
group 'org.example.myproject'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':myviewer')
}
```

And this is my [android] setting.gradle file:

```
rootProject.name = 'Mywidget'
include ':myviewer'
project(':myviewer').projectDir = new File('../myviewer')
```

When i try flutter run, here is the error:

> flutter run   Launching lib/main.dart on Aquaris U2 in debug mode...
>                                                                            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:                                                                 Build file
>     '/user/path/dev/FlutterPlugin/myproject/android/build.gradle' line: 37
> - What went wrong:                                                       A problem occurred evaluating project ':mywidget'.
>
> Project with path ':myviewer' could not be found in project ':mywidget'.
>
> - Try:                                                                   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>     or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
>     insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>                                                                          BUILD FAILED in 908ms
>     Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>     Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done
>     2,1s Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Any idea on how to make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57075972/8219832) that put me on the right track.
After building the .aar using `gradle aR` in command line, i've created the folder libs in my android folder and the just add this line to my root build.gradle `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])`, more explanation about this on [developper.android web site](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)

Comment: `> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade => Non-directory inputs must have .jar extension` , this is the error i receive on running `flutter run`

Comment: Did you slove the comment's issue? I met the same problem, but have no idea to slove it :(

Comment: It's so suck that I made a `Invalid Cache/Restart` with Android Studio not working, but I use `gradlew clean`, and everything works as usual... Another annoying cache bug, hope this could help someone...