# How should I properly setup flutter project to run android plugin

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to create flutter plugin, but unfortunately I have some problems. When I run `flutter run` command, I see output:

```
Couldn't read file LocalFile: 'E:\Workspace\vision-plugin\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\VisionPlugin.kt' even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read permission and try again.
```

I think the main problem is how is organized my `android` directory. My plugin class exists under:

`E:\Workspace\vision-plugin\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\VisionPlugin.kt`

instead of

`E:\Workspace\vision-plugin\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\VisionPlugin.kt`

(there is an extra `app` directory, which is my gradle module). I was wondering if there is a way to make flutter to read from direcory which includes `app` directory. 
In my `pubspec.yaml`, I have defined:

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    androidPackage: com.example
    pluginClass: VisionPlugin
```

Does anyone faced this issue and knows how to solve it?
I have to keep `app` directory, as its gradle module. I've introduced modules, because I needed to add third-party .aar file, which is later used in my plugin
So my project has a structure:

```
vision_plugin
 |_android
   |_app
     |_src
     |_build.gradle
   |_some-library
     |_some-library.aar
     |_build.gradle
   |_buid.gradle
   |_settings.gradle
 |_ios
 |_example
 |_lib
 |_test
 |_pubspec.yaml
```

Comment: Why not make a new project `flutter create -t plugin --androidx --org=org.someorg pluginName`. Run it immediately with `cd pluginName/example; flutter run` then open it in the IDE and copy across anything useful from the original.

Comment: @RichardHeap I've updated my message. I think that I have to keep app directory in my project, as I need additional module `some-library` with .aar file in android part.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971022/how-to-use-local-aar-inside-flutter-plugin/57075972#57075972

Comment: It looks very useful, will check this. Thank you!