# React Native [0.66.4][Android] - Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm using a `react-native` library, and when I'm trying to Rebuild project on Android Studio, I get the below error -

> Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :library-name project caused this error**

Although I do have `aar` file in the android folder of the library I'm using.

I'm using

> 1. react-native - 0.66.4
> 2. gradle version - 6.9

And below is the `build.gradle` present in Android folder of library I'm using.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'

}
```

### Edit

Below is the picture of library I've mentioned above. In this library, I'm testing it in `_test` folder. And `_test` is just a normal `react-native` project.

And it's the `.aar` file inside libs (which is selected in picture) which I've mentioned in above question.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate the issue a bit more.

Comment: @S.Hashmi basically I'm not able to use this library because I think I'm not able to access aar file of android folder from the library I'm using

Comment: @S.Hashmi I've updated my question with "Edit" part, can you please check it now.

Comment: Hello, please provide a minimal reproducer so we can help you

Comment: @jacouille can you please tell which part of question I can explain to you?

Comment: We need more code in order to be able to reproduce it, could you please create a repo with minimal example of the bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following

1. Place .aar file to android/app/libs directory
2. Add following code snippet to app build.gradle (just above dependencies for example)

```
allprojects {
    repositories{
        flatDir{
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

3. Add following to app build gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/name-of-the-lib.aar')
```

Comment: I've updated my question with "Edit" part, can you please check it now.
Because I can't keep my `.aar` file in android folder of my `_test` project

Comment: Have you tried solutions given here? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878599/error-building-android-library-direct-local-aar-file-dependencies-are-not-supp

Comment: I'm unable to understand few solutions because I don't know android or gradle, I've only worked on react-native. And I did implement few solutions which didn't work. Can you please help me?