# How to reference multiple aar artifacts in a com.android.library module?

Tags: android, android-library, aar, android-jetifier

In my Android application project I am trying to **avoid** referencing an external Maven repository in my project from where I would load **multiple** .aar artifacts which make up **one** SDK.

Instead, I would like to put the .aar files **into** my project and then reference them from one of my Gradle **Android library modules**.

I already tried different approaches - none worked, though.

## Approach 1: Composite build (`includeBuild`)

- Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/72672032/35689
- Here my artifact(s) cannot be resolved by Gradle.
- I also tried this in isolation with the [sample project](https://github.com/rsicarelli/SpotifySdkCompositeBuild) - for some reason it does not work with my artifacts. In the example there is only one .aar file which might be the reason.

## Approach 2: One module per aar

- Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074787/356895
- Here I end up with this error:

  > jetified-externallibrary-1.2.3/res/values/values.xml:113:5-122:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/shimmer_auto_start' not found.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually add all of the `.aar` file's dependencies to your project in order to make this work. You will also have to substitute the maven dependency with the `.aar` file manually.

The reason is that an individual `.aar` file does not contain any metadata like maven coordinates, version, dependencies, etc. Therefore Gradle cannot handle any of this for you automatically.