# Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. Android Release Build

Tags: android, react-native

Debug build is running fine but issue generated at time-of release build generation.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':ct-react-native-datatrans:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar'.

  > Error while evaluating property 'hasLocalAarDeps' of task ':ct-react-native-datatrans:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar'
  > > Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :ct-react-native-datatrans project caused this error: /Users/sohan/lab/mapl/mapl-app-datatarans/node_modules/ct-react-native-datatrans/android/libs/android-sdk-1.5.1.aar

Comment: It's possible that this question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878599/error-building-android-library-direct-local-aar-file-dependencies-are-not-supp