# what's the working way to importing local .aar based modules to my android project in 2023

Tags: android

I'm completely new to handling gradle and importing such modules, i have seen many tutorials and solutions but none of them seem to work and generate different errors mostly due to being outdated and incompatible with the updated nature of android studio.

in my project i'm trying to import the downloaded [zebra rfid sdk](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-116/tutorials/tutcreateprojectandroidstudio/) which based on an .aar file, the documentation already mentions the method of importing the module after downloading it and how to use it BUT the way provided doesn't work in my kotlin project.

i tried to import the module manually but i kept getting all kinds of errors, one of the nearly successfull attempts was by following the steps mentioned in [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074787/10997397)

but this still failed as i'm getting an "Failed to resolve: :RFIDAPI3Library" error

my app build.gradle looks like this

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    api (":RFIDAPI3Library")
}
```

project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.3" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

project structure
[image]