# Include Dependencies in Android SDK (AAR file)

Tags: android-studio

does anyone have experience including all the dependencies while exporting android SDK (.aar) without publishing it to other platforms.

I need to include all the dependencies in the SDK (.aar) so later clients just implement the SDK in their project without importing any dependencies, is this possible?

Comment: `java-native-library` is a tag, which should be removed, because there's no such thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add .aar dependency in library module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765190/how-to-add-aar-dependency-in-library-module)

Comment: No Martin, i need to include the transitive library in the SDK i export