# Way To Search for a Gradle Plugin

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I am trying to convert an existing project from Eclipse to Android Studio

I want to put as many of the dependancies as possible as Gradle Plugins pulled from the jcenter() or mavenCentral() repositories

I am somewhat confused as how to search for these
None of the three websites I have found do not return satisfying results

http://plugins.gradle.org

http://mvnrepository.com

https://bintray.com

The best of the three seems to be mvnrepository

None of the three returned a result for Microsoft Live SDK. Is it correct to assume that there does not exist a plugin for this and I have to include it as a project ?

My dependancies generated by the import into Studio - except for Facebook which I changed

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
compile project(':liveSdk')
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:18.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev119-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This libraries will be resolved from remote repositories:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:18.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

This is a project in your workspace:

```
compile project(':liveSdk')
```

And this are the files in your libs folder:

```
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev119-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
```

So if you had a liveSDK project in your Eclipse you should import it too.
I hope it was helpful.

Comment: I am aware of the meanings of the dependencies. What I am  asking is how to convert the jars to repositories, easily

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. If you actually have a jar from liveSDK locally you can use a flatDir repo. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file

Answer (score 0):

I usually go to Maven Central to look for published gradle libraries:

http://search.maven.org/

Just type in the name of your jar, and you will most likely see the published gradle libraries.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for a more flexible search like just typing facebooksdk and finding the right one without the full package name

Comment: Yeah you don't need to full package name. If you type 'Facebook' into maven central, it will give you several options. But then ultimately you do need to know the full package name to pick which lib you want

Comment: That is not quite true, if you type Facebook you get a long list and it is up to you to scan through it to find the relevant package. It would be helpful if the most likely or popular packages were on top. I do not find the search efficient. It is ok if you have one or two packages but more you start wasting time

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes it is relatively inefficient, though hopefully you will only have to go through it once.