# How to build program with IntelliJ and run it on Linux?

Tags: java, gradle

I wrote a simple terminal program in IntelliJ. I'm using Gradle (and I actually don't know how to use it).

I can run the program inside IntelliJ IDE, everything works fine.

Now I want to copy it to another machine: Debian with Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14).

My program uses an external library (jaunt0.9.9.9.jar).

I have added this libary in "Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Add".

I guess I have to make a -.jar file, but when I run "MyProjectName [jar]" task - I'm getting an error like this:

src\main\java\Hello\MyProjectName.java:3: error: package com.jaunt does not exist import com.jaunt.*;

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You add a dependency but it is an external one. You must use "Attach jar" in the dependencies.

Comment: `java -cp <insert pathTo jaunt0.9.9.9.jar> MyProjectName.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the '`application`' plugin in Gradle it will do everything you need to package up the application and deploy it to another machine.

In your `build.gradle` add this plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

Specify the main class to run

```
mainClassName = "org.gradle.sample.Main"
```

Then run the task

```
$ gradle distZip
```

This will create a zip file you can copy to a machine which includes a shell script for launching.

For more information see the Gradle page on the [application plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a dependency declaration in your project's `build.gradle` file. You added the correct dependency manually in IntelliJ, but this does not automatically add the dependency declaration to the build file.

In `build.gradle` try adding something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('relative_path_to_jar/jaunt0.9.9.9.jar')
}
```

Also, see [answers to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file).