# Gradle- Importing a JAR file with absolute windows path?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

How do I import a JAR file as a dependency through a full Windows URL? I'm trying to import JAR file on a network drive (labeled "H") and I cannot use Maven Central easily because of our silly firewall.

when I try to use `compile files` I still get compile errors due to the dependency classes not being found.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files ("H/Processes/Development/libraries/hikari-cp/HikariCP-2.4.1.jar")

}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
    main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
}


jar { 
    from configurations.compile.collect { entry -> zipTree(entry) }
}
```

Comment: You left out the colon after `H`.

Comment: use h: like MirMasej said, you might find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311386/problems-during-build-when-referencing-static-lib-directory-gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an error in your path. It should be corrected like this.

**H:/Processes/Development/libraries/hikari-cp/HikariCP-2.4.1.jar**

If you want to add more than one jar file as dependencies, here is how to do it(relative path is used in here)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: '../../lib', include: '**/*.jar')
}
```

Comment: So much inconsistency with url syntax, but I'm glad this works. Thanks!