# How to add a local .jar file dependency to a remote repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to add a .jar file to a remote repository using gradle. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file) question, and the steps described [here](https://login.gradle.org/docs/submit) and [here](https://login.gradle.org/docs/publish-plugin) I have come up with the following **build.gradle** file:

```
// First, apply the publishing plugin
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.gradle.publish:plugin-publish-plugin:0.9.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.gradle.plugin-publish"
// Apply other plugins here, e.g. java plugin for a plugin written in java or
// the groovy plugin for a plugin written in groovy
apply plugin: "java"
// If your plugin has any external java dependencies, Gradle will attempt to
// downloaded them from JCenter for anyone using the plugins DSL
// so you should probably use JCenter for dependency resolution in your own
// project.
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
  compile localGroovy() //not needed for Java plugins
  // other dependencies that your plugin requires
  compile fileTree(dir: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/", include: ["*.jar"])
  compile fileTree(dir: "/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/", include: ["*.jar"])
}

// Unless overridden in the pluginBundle config DSL, the project version will
// be used as your plugin version when publishing
version = "0.1.0"
group = "org.fiware.kiara.kiaragen"

// The configuration example below shows the minimum required properties
// configured to publish your plugin to the plugin portal
pluginBundle {
  credentials {
    username "Sebi"
    password "**************"
  }
  url = "https://plugins.gradle.org"
  description = "kiaragen 0.1.0"
  tags = ["fiware", "kiara", "kiaragen"]

  plugins {
    kiaragenPlugin {
      id = "org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen"
      displayName = "kiaragen 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

The .jar file I want to publish is:

```
/usr/local/bin/kiaragen-0.1.0.jar
```

When I try to publish the plugin(**kiaragen-0.1.0.jar**) I get the following error:

```
$ gradle publishPlugins

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/Uploadkiaragen/build.gradle' line: 42

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Uploadkiaragen'.
> Could not find method credentials() for arguments [build_4zc9ztisu145lwynn3m693mcz$_run_closure3_closure4@430b2699] on root project 'Uploadkiaragen'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

When I remove the credential attributes I get:

```
$ gradle publishPlugins

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/Uploadkiaragen/build.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Uploadkiaragen'.
> No such property: url for class: com.gradle.publish.PluginBundleExtension

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

It's not very clear to me what's happening at this point: does gradle try to publish the publishing plugin or my plugin using the publishing plugin?

**Edit:**

I have modified the **pluginBundle** section of **build.gradle** to:

```
// The configuration example below shows the minimum required properties
// configured to publish your plugin to the plugin portal
pluginBundle {

  website = "http://www.gradle.org/"
  vcsUrl = "https://github.com/gradle/gradle"
  description = "kiaragen 0.1.0"
  tags = ["fiware", "kiara", "kiaragen"]

  plugins {
    kiaragenPlugin {
      id = "org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen"
      displayName = "kiaragen 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

The publish operation now returns:

```
$ gradle publishPlugins

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/Uploadkiaragen/build.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Uploadkiaragen'.
> No such property: url for class: com.gradle.publish.PluginBundleExtension

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.688 secs
[kiara@kiara Uploadkiaragen]$ gradle publishPlugins
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:publishPluginJar
:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:publishPluginJavaDocsJar
:publishPlugins FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishPlugins'.
> No plugin descriptor for plugin ID 'org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen'.
  Create a 'META-INF/gradle-plugins/org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen.properties' file with a 'implementation-class' property pointing to the plugin class implementation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Why do I need to:

```
Create a 'META-INF/gradle-plugins/org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen.properties' file with a 'implementation-class' property pointing to the plugin class implementation.
```

when I simply want to upload a .jar file?

Comment: You're trying to publish a gradle plugin?

Comment: No, just upload a .jar file and all of its dependencies here: https://plugins.gradle.org

Comment: I'm confused. That's where you publish gradle plugins... But you say you're not trying to publish one

Comment: Sorry, I meant yes. My plugin consists of a .jar file and its dependencies.