# How to add external jar files in gradle project inside the netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jar, gradle, dependencies

I have created the Gradle web app which is running inside the NetBeans. Now I want to add some external jar files in it so how can I add the jar from NetBeans.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your Gradle project to add your dependency and refresh it in NetBeans to pick up the changes. There is plenty of documentation how to do it. For example [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to take that .jar from a local directory,

Add next to your module gradle (Not the app gradle file):

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}


dependencies {
   compile name: 'gson-2.2.4'
}
```

ref:[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)