# How to add WEB-INF/lib jar in war build using GRADLE script

Tags: gradle

I have common lib folder and have multiple project. so in this case I am referring jar, but while build those jar which I kept in lib not includes in war building thru gradle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file might help

Comment: The best idea is to add the file when the war file is built, not afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Once your war created , use same war and thru copy war add jar to appropiate path