# Adding dependencies for gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have in gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'something:1.0'
}
```

What I need to add in the file to add a local .jar file, which java can "import"?
But I don't need to include this .jar in my application. Just like a shared library.

I tried:

```
classpath 'something:1.0','somethingelse:1.0'
classpath 'something:1.0, somethingelse:1.0'
classpath { 'something:1.0','somethingelse:1.0' }
compile files('somethingelse.jar')
classpath files('lib/somethingelse.jar')
classpath fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
```

Comment: Have you tried `providedCompile files('somethingelse.jar')`? This will make your `somethingelse.jar` available at the classpath during compile, but doesn't package it into the final artifact

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'blah-blah'.
> Could not find method providedCompile() for arguments [file collection] on org
.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorat

Comment: Have you applied the `war` plugin? Or what kind of application is it? If not WEB-APP, how is this lib provided?

Comment: It's a java application. No, no 'war' plugin

Comment: It's not web. And it's not important how other libs provided

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `compile name:` This recipie is in a gradle file I inherited.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }


dependencies {
    compile name: 'jdom'
    compile name: 'jebl-0.3'
}
```

---

BTW, this question appears to be a duplicate of

[How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)