# Gradle equivalent to maven systemPath

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies

I can't figure out what to put in gradle to satisfy this dependency:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jnlp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jnlp-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file ?

Answer (score 7):

You can add a dependency on any file within the local filesystem, as:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("$System.env.JAVA_HOME" + '/lib/javaws.jar')
}
```

Read about it in the official [userguide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies).

Comment: If you have Oracle JDK 8, use `compile files("$System.env.JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/javaws.jar")`