# Including alternate jar from repository dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am migrating a project from Maven to Gradle and everything seems to be going well. I am however, getting caught up on a particular dependency.

In maven pom.xml the dependency was included as such:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>models</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/libs/models-templates-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I have been looking into how to achieve something like this in gradle and haven't found a clear answer.

I thought I would need to first download the entire directory and extract the dependency so I started looking at this solution: [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)

However, after looking into what is happening a little more I've found that I actually need to declare an alternative jar name to download. So I still need it to look in the correct "models" group name but I need to download the "models-tempaltes" jar instead.

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)

Comment: So I started off with that question. I think i might be on track. The difference is that I need i need to extract a specific jar from a dependency and include it in the classpath before the project is compiled.

Comment: I took a look at my setup a little more to make sure I couldn't solve it with the solution provided in the question you mentioned @MichaelEaster, I think it is different, if not please feel free to correct me and i'll close this. I've edited the question to reflect the situation more clearly.

Comment: If however I was downloading an entire directory and then needing to copy a file over I was able to find my way to a solution starting with the answer provided there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this.

The alternative to the pom.xml pattern of:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>models</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/libs/models-templates-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

would be

```
compile (group = 'com.company', name = 'models', version = '1.0.0') {
  artifact {
    name = 'models-data-template'
    type = 'jar'
    extension = 'jar'
  }
}
```

Important to note that this needed both the type and extension properties to work, I tried w/ just the alternative name and that caused a bunch of errors.

Hope this helps someone.