# android studio, which import statement to use external libs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import

I added the EJML library to my android studio project, but i dont know how the import statement looks like.

I mean, what do i have to write to use these libraries?

[image]

my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/EJML-core-0.30.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-core-0.30-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-dense64-0.30.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-dense64-0.30-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-denseC64-0.30.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-denseC64-0.30-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-equation-0.30.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-equation-0.30-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-simple-0.30.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-simple-0.30-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/EJML-core-0.30-sources.jar')
```

}

Comment: If you give me a -1, please let me know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app level `build.gradle` file, you'll have a `dependencies` section.

see [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file) for more information.

So in your case you would have:

```
dependencies {
    ... library files that are already there
    compile files('libs/EJML-core-0.30.jar')
    compile files('libs/EJML-core-0.30-sources.jar')
    ... the libraries in your libs folder will follow the same pattern
}
```

**Edit:** added from comments.

> but i dont know how the import statement looks like: import ....

if you just use a class from the `JAR` files, so for example if I add a dependency for a `RecyclerView` (example: `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'`) I would then call `RecyclerView` `recyclerView = new RecyclerView()` etc and it'll ask you to import it there. I don't know what classes are required for the `JARs` you have compiled.

Comment: thanks, but i dont know how the import statement looks like: import ....

Comment: if you just use a class from the JAR files, so for example if I add a dependency for a RecyclerView (example: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1') I would then call RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView() etc and it'll ask you to import it there. I don't know what classes are required for the JARs you have compiled.