# Modify build.gradle to reference local jar

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

(Note that I am a novice at Eclipse / Gradle, so please bear with me.)

I am trying to modify the following project because there is a customization I would like to make:  https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup

In turn, I would like to the use the modified binary in the following project:  https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup-gradle-project-template

Overall I believe I need to do the following steps:

1. Download the source for that project and compile it to a local .jar file
2. Modify the "template project" build.gradle to reference the local .jar

I think I got step #1 to work by importing the Gradle project into Eclipse, going to Gradle Tasks, right clicking "jar" and running the task.  A .jar is generated.

After that, I download the template project and copy the generated .jar into the libs folder of the template project.  Then I modify build.gradle:

I comment out the following line under buildscript > dependencies

```
//classpath "io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup:1.0.1"
```

Then I added the following to the top of the file per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    runtime files('libs/swagger2markup-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

(I also tried using `compile` instead of `runtime`, as well as `fileTree`.)

No matter what I do, the template project seems to download the remote (unmodified) binary.

How do I force the project to use the local file?

Comment: How do your other dependencies looks like? Maybe it's being downloaded as a transitive dependency. Try running `gradle dependencies` and see if you can trace where does it come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the dependency is also declared in the plugin as you can see here:

https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle

That means that the Dependency manager sees that and downloads it. First, you have to exclude it:

```
classpath 'io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-gradle-plugin:1.2.0', {
  exclude group: 'io.github.swagger2markup', module: 'swagger2markup-gradle-plugin'
}
```

And the same for `io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-import-files-ext`. Then you put **your** library on the classpath. So

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }
        //mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3'
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.10.1'
        classpath 'io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-gradle-plugin:1.2.0', {
          exclude group: 'io.github.swagger2markup', module: 'swagger2markup-gradle-plugin'
        }
        classpath files('libs/swagger2markup-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')   // YOUR VERSION
        classpath "io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-import-files-ext:1.2.0", {
          exclude group: 'io.github.swagger2markup', module: 'swagger2markup-gradle-plugin'
        }
        classpath "com.bluepapa32:gradle-watch-plugin:0.1.5"
        classpath "org.kordamp.gradle:livereload-gradle-plugin:0.2.1"
    }
}
```

EDIT: And you have to use the dependency as a buildscript dependency, that means it must be declared inside `buildscript { dependencies { ... } }` not just in `dependencies { ... }`