# How to make Gradle fail the build if a file dependency is not found?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle build that has some dependencies of the form

```
compile files('path/to/local/lib.jar')
```

(the build is being migrated - eventually these will be replaced)

The build failed because one of these paths was incorrectly specified. But it failed due to a compile error - it looked like Gradle silently ignored the missing dependency.

Is there a simple option or switch that will force Gradle to fail the build if any dependency (particularly local file dependencies) cannot be resolved (eg., file missing)?

Edit: to clarify further:

If a dependency cannot be found in the configured repositories, Gradle will fail the build when attempting to resolve them, as expected.

BUT - if a dependency is defined as "compile files ....", and the file specified does not exist at build time, Gradle will IGNORE that error, and attempt compilation anyway. That seems **spectacularly** wrong-headed and inconsistent default behaviour.

My question is - is there a Gradle option or switch or environment variable or system property that I can set to force Gradle to verify that file dependencies exist?  (E.g,, behave in a sane and rational way?)

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of an old thread, but given that none of the currently proposed solutions actually works, and the solution appears to be trivial (collating two of them), I am leaving it here for future reference.

The point here is that we simply want to ensure that the files do exist, so we can just use the `exists()` method of the `File` class:

```
task ensureDepsExist() {
    doLast {
        configurations.implementation.canBeResolved(true)
        Set<File> impFiles = configurations.implementation.resolve()

        impFiles.forEach { f ->
            if (!f.exists()) {
                ant.fail "${f} could not be found"
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn ensureDepsExist
```

The `canBeResolved()` call is required, or Gradle will complain that `configurations` dependencies cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can check transitive dependencies using Gradle 7.3 (example: Fail if the project depends on log4j directly or transitively).

**Kotlin DSL**

```
configurations {
  all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      eachDependency {
        if (requested.name == "log4j") {
          throw RuntimeException("Project depends on log4j")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Groovy DSL**

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.name == 'log4j') {
            throw new RuntimeException("Project depends on log4j")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the Kotlin DSL section.  relsolutionStrategy should be resolutionStrategy

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as shown below. It is not a built-in Gradle function but does not require code to check each dependency specifically (it checks all in the `compile` configuration):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files('lib/abc.jar')
    compile files('lib/def.jar')
}

task checkDependencies() {
    doLast {
        configurations.compile.each { file ->
            assert file.exists() 
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn checkDependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

To fail the build you can:

```
ant.fail('message why it failed')
```

Then you can craft a condition then fail the build with nice message ;)

I would suggest to create a task that will bring the file to the project first with a condition to check if the file is available etc if not then throw a Gradle exception and fail the build with a message, and execute the task first in the execution phase.

I have no chance to test it now but it could be something like this, correct me if any syntax is wrong - but you should get the idea.

```
def yourDep = $/\path\to\your\depdendency/$

task bringDeps << {

  if (yourDep.exists()){
    copy {
      from yourDep
      into $projectDir/depsOrSmthg
    }
  } else{
  ant.fail('message why it failed')
  }

}
```

Comment: That's useful, but I was hoping for/asking if there is some sort of built-in Gradle function that would verify the existance of dependencies, rather than having to write custom code to check each one.

Comment: Oh sorry, David I am not sure, you depend on a file there, I'm not saying there is not but, I doubt it.

Comment: In other hand I would suggest to use something like Nexus if you have loads of dependencies like you said, then you can specify another repository and use normal dependency syntax and it will check for existence and what you probably look for.

Comment: This is a legacy build that I'm migrating ... so lots of libraries just in various /lib folders at the moment.  I could set up Artifactory as a caching proxy for the build, and put local files in there temporarily, but I was hoping that Gradle would be slightly more helpful...

Comment: @David did that helped in any way? if yes please remember about http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

```
task ensureDependenciesExist() {
    doLast {
        configurations.implementation.canBeResolved(true)
        DependencySet deps = configurations.implementation.getDependencies()
        Set<File> impFiles = configurations.implementation.resolve()
        deps.each { d ->
            boolean depWasResolved = impFiles.any { impFile -> impFile.name.find(".*${d.name}.*${d.version}") }
            if (!depWasResolved) {
                println "${d} was not resolved"
                assert depWasResolved
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn ensureDependenciesExist
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Appreciate the effort to answer a question. But, instead of just writing a piece of code, please consider explaining your answer to give little bit of context to your answer. This could help readers.

Comment: not to mention, this code fails miserably even in the most trivial of cases