# Fail the Gradle build when dependencies are not available

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, nexus

`build.gradle` (unnecessary parts were ommited):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("com.example:some-lib:1.0.0-RELEASE")
}
```

Assume that the defined dependency is missing in configured Maven repository. When `./gradlew clean build` tasks are executed the application is built successfully, although the required dependencies are missing.

**Is there a way to configure Gradle to fail if there are unresolved dependencies?**

---

Relates to:

- [How to make Gradle fail the build if a file dependency is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527631/how-to-make-gradle-fail-the-build-if-a-file-dependency-is-not-found) - Solution provided there is not applicable.

Comment: which version of Gradle are you using? I use versions >= 4.8 and Gradle build fails as expected if any dependency is missing.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I'm using version `4.8.1`.

Comment: Even in lower versions, a `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':*****' Could not resolve ****` should be triggered by default

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I use 4.10.3 and the build not fails. I call `./gradlew dependencies` to check the dependencies

Comment: @Davide the task `dependencies` will execute successfully, but it will mark as `FAILED` the missing/invalid dependencies in the output dependencies graph.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti yes correct, but the build not fails if there are missing dependencies.

Comment: @Davide this is were we disagree: in current Gradle version  (and also in older versions I have used),  I always have build failing when missing dependencies, as described in the answer below. strage that you don't have this behavior

Comment: 'gradle dependencies' will NOT fail even with missing dependencies, but 'gradle build' WILL fail if that's the case. The question could be better phrased, since it suggests 'gradle clean build', which SHOULD fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this `build.gradle` (**note:** intentionally bogus jar specified in `dependencies`):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("junit:junit:4.12")
    compile("junit:junitxyz:51.50")
}

task checkDependencies() {
    doLast {
        configurations.compile.each { file ->
            println "TRACER checking: " + file.name
            assert file.exists() 
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn checkDependencies
```

example output:

```
$ gradle -q clean compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[snip]

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compile'.
   > Could not find junit:junitxyz:51.50.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junitxyz/51.50/junitxyz-51.50.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junitxyz/51.50/junitxyz-51.50.jar
```