# How do I include com.sun.tools JAR in my Gradle JAR classpath buildscript and also sync with my IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I need the com.sun.tools jar as a compile dependency, so I just copied it to my libs folder in my Intellij project.  However, I'm trying to use gradle.  I only need it as a dependency for ONE of my modules.  How do I do this.  I currently have this in my module jar task:

```
jar {

    from('build/classes/main/')
    from('libs/tools.jar')

    manifest {
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': '1.0',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {"../lib/${it.name}" },
}
```

I also tried this in my module's "dependencies" closure:

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
```

I also just tried putting the jar on my entire project classpath and it's still not compiling:

```
    classpath ":tools"
```

Maybe it's correct but my IDE isn't refreshing correctly? I have the plugin already

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

and it's been working perfectly until I try to do this.

EDIT: it's for an annotation processor, so I'm trying to include it in my module jar build and not have other modules depend on it.  Is there a better way to do it than copying the jar?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20956456/104891) should work. In IntelliJ IDEA it should be enough to have `tools.jar` in the JSDK configuration classpath.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, nah, figured it out though.  I'll post the answer in the morning thought thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to express dependency on tools.jar without copying the jar:

```
dependencies {
  compile files("${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../lib/tools.jar")
}
```

Intellij 2017.1 is able to recognize and import it as a module dependency without issues.

It only works when run on JDK though, as bare JRE has no tools.jar included.

Comment: Yep, that worked for me! Working perfectly now, thanks.  Time to mess around with the compiler now