# Build and compile external library in Android

Tags: android, gradle

I'd like to build my android application using stub (as android.jar) and at run time use library which is located in device shell.

In build.gradle i wrote:

```
dependencies {
  provided files('mylib.jar')
}
```

but i still see the library in apk in instant-run.zip (mylib-classes.dex)

Comment: What have you tried so far? That's the first link I've come across after typing "android gradle add jar dependency": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file

Comment: I want to link to my library in android device as sdk is linked. In sdk you use stub in some cases, the full implementation exists in device. I want tu achive something similar

Answer (score 0):

Place the jar in app/libs, and in app/build.gradle add in the dependencies section:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['file_name.jar'])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I did it. But still I can see those library in instan-run.zip

Comment: So what is the issue in seeing those ? If you satisfied with the answer then give an upvote.

Comment: I want to link to full implementation of my library which is in my device. You dont see any part of android.jar (which is located in /system/framwork/android.jar) but you link to stub while building app in Android Studio for example

Answer (score 0):

Place the jar in app/libs, and in app/build.gradle add in the dependencies section:

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['file_name.jar'])
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Copy file `mylib.jar` to libs folder.

In `build.gradle`

```
 dependencies {
    compile files('libs/markdownview-1.2.jar')
 }
```