# How to include an Intellij gradle project inside another Intellij gradle project?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, bukkit

I have two java projects as Bukkit/Spigot plugins. Both projects are using gradle, private repositories, and one project should inherit from another.

Projects:
SpigotCore - Contains database management and utility classes. This is the "main" project.
Minigame Framework - Runs minigames. Needs database access and utility class access.

What is the best way to make the Minigame Framework inherit from the SpigotCore project using gradle?  I have been unsuccessful in getting Intellij module dependency working. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just compiling the SpigotCore and then including the jar file in my build.gradle file.

Answer used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956456/2865125

Now following the answer above, it shaded the SpigotCore classes into the MinigameFramework. This is not what we want since both projects are Bukkit plugins and will be provided at runtime. So I changed "compile" to "provided" and it works great!

The change:

```
dependencies {
    provided files("somePath/spigotcore.jar")
}
```