# The gradle.jar should put where?

Tags: android, gradle

Android studio need "grade.jar" when open project. The message is

> download ：http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.3.3/gradle-core-2.3.3.jar

However，my AS too slowly to download it，so I download it form network station. I want to ask this gradle.jar should put where?

Comment: you mean the Gradle wrapper? what is _grade.jar_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is answered in this  [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file) clearly. try this out, let me know any changes