# How to use Kotlin with H2 and SQLite in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

When I try to use Kotlin in Intellij with either SQLite or H2, Intellij gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion.connect(Database.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion.connect$default(Database.kt:90)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:9)
```

This is my Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.20'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.h2.Driver"
    }
}

group '1'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.9.1'

}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

This is my Kotlin file, where I try to use [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki) to interface with H2e some data persistence with Kotlin:

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.StdOutSqlLogger
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.insert
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.selectAll

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Database.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test", driver = "org.h2.Driver")

    transaction {
        logger.addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)

        val stPeteId = Cities.insert {
            it[name] = "St. Petersburg"
        } get Cities.id

        println("Cities: ${Cities.selectAll()}")
    }
}

object Cities : Table() {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
    val name = varchar("name", 50)
}

data class City(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

How do I use Kotlin with a database? This is not for Android; just a personal project in Intellij that I want to use eventually on a PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need the h2 driver, wether you're in java or kotlin.
Add the com.h2database:h2 dependency to your gradle file and add the maven central if needed.

By the way, there's nothing wrong with your kotlin code. This would also not work if called from java like this, since you're missing the dependencies.

Comment: I added the .jar file to the library, so it should be in the classpath. I have also never used Gradle before, so I think it is a gradle problem.

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ try to add the jar in the module settings as a library.

Comment: As in: Click on the Project -> Press F4 -> Modules/<Project>/Dependencies -> +

Comment: If you want to do it using the gradle file check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700183/2232127

Comment: Thanks! I added `compile "com.h2database:h2.1.4.196"` to the dependencies section of my Gradle file and it works.