# Running task in the beginning in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle. In my project, I have a requirement to download all jars from different locations to a single folder before proceeding with the compilation. How I can achieve this?

Any lead on this will really help.

Thanks,
Shruti

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by download all jars from different locations to a single folder before proceeding with the compilation. Doesn't adding those dependencies in `build.gradle` help you?

Comment: Hi, in build.gradle only I want to mention the task. In dependencies section I want to specify something like this : dependencies {
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'3.8.1'
   compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version:'2.8.6'
   // some jars directly I want to mention here and that needs to be downloaded from different url. I don't have maven artifacts for them.
  }

Comment: you probably want this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file