# importing dependencies into eclipse using gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I've got what appears to be an adequate gradle file but eclipse refuses to recognise the dependancy I'm trying to import (despite refreshing the gradle project after implementing the dependancy)

My gradle file lacks a `buildscript{}` block but I'm not familar enough with gradle to implement it. My build file was autogenerated by eclipse so I don't see why it'd be an issue.

I'm trying to import `"com.intrinio:sdk:0.0.1"`

**build.gradle:**

```
// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'


    compile "com.intrinio:sdk:0.0.1"

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: Where does `intrinio` come from ?

Comment: @ToYonos https://github.com/intrinio

Comment: Do you have Buildship installed and working? Feels like you skipped over telling us that.

Comment: Where is `com.intrinio:sdk:0.0.1` coming from? Your `build.gradle` says, download it from JCenter, but it's not there. Looks like you're gonna have to build it yourself first and then [add the dependency locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20700053/6505250).

Comment: @nitind yeah buildship is installed and working

Answer (score 0):

I think this is [the lib](https://github.com/intrinio/java-sdk) you want to use.

As it's not deployed in a public repository, you have to manually install it. Checkout the project from github and do as below :

> Installation
>
> To install the Intrinio Java SDK to your local Maven repository, simply execute:
>
> `mvn install`

Then, in your gradle file, add `mavenLocal()` in the `repository` section and it should just work fine.

Comment: But the installation link says I can install it using gradle:
`https://github.com/intrinio/java-sdk#installation`