# Android Studio java module dependancy from local directory

Tags: java, android, module, dependencies, local

I have a question regarding whether module dependencies in a java app built in Android studio can be sourced from a local directory instead of an online repository. The code in question is in `build.gradle` and looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
}
```

This will pull files from a repository into the project at build time. But say I would like to download the dependency (say, from GitHub) and store it locally on my file system and include it into the project from there. How would this be done?

I've tried the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation '~/path/to/files/'
}
```

But I get the error `Supplied String module notation '~/path/to/files/' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.` (where `~/path/to/files/` is a real path)

The reason I ask is because I'd like to use a library in my project and include it as a dependency. The library is on GitHub. But I'd like to make some changes to it before it's imported. The only solution I can think of is to download it, make the changes and then uploaded as my own forked library back to GitHub again and it include that. But if I can somehow just work on it locally, I'd prefer that. Any ideas?

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file ?

Comment: That might offer a solution, but I don't seem to have a `libs` directory, When implementing a filetree do I specify the name of the directory, and where do I need to put the folder inside the project?